# Exception writing ByteBuffer field into Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, nio, apache-beam, datastax-java-driver

We have an apache beam dataflow job that reads the data from Big Query converts them into POJO before writing into Cassandra using Datastax driver. I recently added a new blob column to the table and added a ByteBuffer field to the POJO.

How I am creating the ByteBuffer

```
String str = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(installSkuAttributes);
byte[] bytes = str.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
pojo.setInstallAttributes(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes));
```

here is the pipeline snippet
    public void executePipeline() throws Exception {

```
Pipeline pipeline = 
Pipeline.create(jobMetaDataBean.getDataflowPipelineOptions());
```

....
    writeDataToCassandra(installSkuData);

```
pipeline.run();
```

After making the necessary changes in the DAO writer I am getting the following exception When I ran the job. I am using Datastax driver

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Forbidden IOException when writing to OutputStream
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner$DirectPipelineResult.waitUntilFinish(DirectRunner.java:349)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner$DirectPipelineResult.waitUntilFinish(DirectRunner.java:319)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run(DirectRunner.java:210)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run(DirectRunner.java:66)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:311)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:297)
    at com.homedepot.productassortment.fullfeed.dataflow.InstallSkusFullFeed.executePipeline(InstallSkusFullFeed.java:216)
    at com.homedepot.productassortment.fullfeed.dataflow.InstallSkusFullFeed.main(InstallSkusFullFeed.java:221)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Forbidden IOException when writing to OutputStream
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.encodeToSafeStream(CoderUtils.java:88)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.encodeToByteArray(CoderUtils.java:69)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.encodeToByteArray(CoderUtils.java:54)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.clone(CoderUtils.java:148)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.MutationDetectors$CodedValueMutationDetector.<init>(MutationDetectors.java:117)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.MutationDetectors.forValueWithCoder(MutationDetectors.java:46)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.ImmutabilityCheckingBundleFactory$ImmutabilityEnforcingBundle.add(ImmutabilityCheckingBundleFactory.java:112)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.ParDoEvaluator$BundleOutputManager.output(ParDoEvaluator.java:242)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:219)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$700(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:69)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:517)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:505)
    at com.homedepot.productassortment.fullfeed.dataflow.InstallSkusFullFeed$PrepareDataForCassandraWrite.processElement(InstallSkusFullFeed.java:160)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.SerializableCoder.encode(SerializableCoder.java:166)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.SerializableCoder.encode(SerializableCoder.java:52)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.IterableLikeCoder.encode(IterableLikeCoder.java:99)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.IterableLikeCoder.encode(IterableLikeCoder.java:60)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder.encode(Coder.java:143)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.encodeToSafeStream(CoderUtils.java:85)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.encodeToByteArray(CoderUtils.java:69)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.encodeToByteArray(CoderUtils.java:54)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.clone(CoderUtils.java:148)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.MutationDetectors$CodedValueMutationDetector.<init>(MutationDetectors.java:117)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.MutationDetectors.forValueWithCoder(MutationDetectors.java:46)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.ImmutabilityCheckingBundleFactory$ImmutabilityEnforcingBundle.add(ImmutabilityCheckingBundleFactory.java:112)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.ParDoEvaluator$BundleOutputManager.output(ParDoEvaluator.java:242)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:219)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$700(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:69)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:517)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:505)
    at com.homedepot.productassortment.fullfeed.dataflow.InstallSkusFullFeed$PrepareDataForCassandraWrite.processElement(InstallSkusFullFeed.java:160)
    at com.homedepot.productassortment.fullfeed.dataflow.InstallSkusFullFeed$PrepareDataForCassandraWrite$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:185)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:149)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.SimplePushbackSideInputDoFnRunner.processElementInReadyWindows(SimplePushbackSideInputDoFnRunner.java:78)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.ParDoEvaluator.processElement(ParDoEvaluator.java:189)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DoFnLifecycleManagerRemovingTransformEvaluator.processElement(DoFnLifecycleManagerRemovingTransformEvaluator.java:55)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectTransformExecutor.processElements(DirectTransformExecutor.java:161)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectTransformExecutor.run(DirectTransformExecutor.java:125)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real problem is here:

> java.io.NotSerializableException: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer

It's caused by the fact that `ByteBuffer` isn't serializable, so it couldn't be used for distributed work. You can avoid this by using `byte[]` directly as your attribute, or implement a wrapper around `ByteBuffer` that will be serializable.

Comment: Can't implement a wrapper since HeapByteBuffer is visible only to java.nio package. I changed to data type to byte[] and the above issue is gone but running into another exception.    `com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [blob <-> [B]
 at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.notFound(CodecRegistry.java:741)
 at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.createCodec(CodecRegistry.java:602)
 at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.findCodec(CodecRegistry.java:582)
 at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.codecFor(CodecRegis

Comment: You can add codec for `byte[]` (https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/custom_codecs/) but I don't know how to integrate it into Beam

Comment: I did but still running into SerializationException since Datastax doesn't handle byte[] well and forced to use ByteBuffer. Later changed to use text column instead of Blob and it is well

Comment: great that you fixed it